# How do I access ten years of craigslist archives?

Tags: data-request, prices

I have a [craigslist archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20060223232941/http://www.craigslist.com/fur/) from which I am trying to extract details and prices about products. I want to extend my search back to the year 2005, but the [tenth page](https://web.archive.org/web/20160221191124/http://www.craigslist.com/fur/index1000.html) tells me "There is nothing here." The [ninth page](https://web.archive.org/web/20060404105544/http://www.craigslist.com/fur/index900.html) is from April 3 of 2015, so relatively recent. How can I access craigslist listings from further back than 2015?

Answer (score 1):

You can see what days the Wayback Machine has archived a given URL by changing the date portion of the URL to an asterisk:

- https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.craigslist.com/fur/index1000.html

The problem is that they've only ever crawled that specific URL once, and it returned a redirect (status 302).

It's possible that there's some other service out there trying to specifically archive Craigslist entries -- Archive.org just takes snapshots every so often, and is much more likely to miss things that were posted in periods when they weren't grabbing snapshots of the site.